# Strange debug message run rails command in docker image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I am getting the following strange output when running ./bin/rails from a docker image ruby:3.0.2. At the end of the normal message about available commands it starts a debugger session (I think). The backtrace appeared when I terminated the debug session with `exit`

Anyone know what the cause is for this?

```
The most common rails commands are:
 generate     Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console      Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server       Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 test         Run tests except system tests (short-cut alias: "t")
 test:system  Run system tests
 dbconsole    Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
              (short-cut alias: "db")
 new          Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
              new application called MyApp in "./my_app"
 plugin new   Create a new Rails railtie or engine

All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
In addition to those commands, there are:

/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/x86_64-linux/continuation.so: warning: callcc is obsolete; use Fiber instead
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

<internal:kernel>:90:
(rdb:1) exit
exit
/usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/debug.rb:240:in `synchronize': deadlock; recursive locking (ThreadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/debug.rb:240:in `check_suspend'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/debug.rb:838:in `trace_func'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/debug.rb:1104:in `block in <class:DEBUGGER__>'
    from ./bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from ./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is your Rails version compatible with Ruby 3.0?

Comment: Yes I am running rails 7.0.0.alpha2. Should have mentioned that!

Comment: Did you find something out regarding this issue?